# Vue.js - Bootstrap Vue Popover interpreting HTML

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component, bootstrap-vue

I would like a popover to display one or multiple hyperlinks when clicked on. I am able to get other Bootstrap elements to interpret HTML by using the `v-html` argument although it is not working in this case.

Here's my code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-button
      :id="popover"
      size="sm"
    >
      Button
    </b-button>
    <b-popover
      :target="popover"
      triggers="focus"
      v-html="actions"
    >
      {{ actions }}
    </b-popover>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    computed: {
      actions() {
        return [
          `<a href="www.google.com">Google</a><br>`,
          `<a href="www.youtube.com">Youtube</a><br>`
        ].join('')
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the binding sign `:` on `target` and `id` then change them to `popover1` then create a nested div with `v-html` directive which has as value `actions` :

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-button
      id="popover1"
      size="sm"
    >
      Button
    </b-button>
    <b-popover
      target="popover1"
      triggers="focus"
    
    >
    <div v-html="actions"></div>
    </b-popover>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    computed: {
      actions() {
        return [
          `<a href="www.google.com">Google</a><br>`,
          `<a href="www.youtube.com">Youtube</a><br>`
        ].join('')
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

If the `id` and `target` attributes are bound to a property you should keep the binding sign.

Comment: For the avoidance of doubt to later readers, you don't have to remove the dynamic binding on ```target``` and ```id``` to make this work. Its just it isn't appropriate in the OP. Putting the ```actions``` inside a ```div``` is the critical part.

Comment: thanks for your comment but i don't understand what do you mean

Comment: Its a very good answer that you gave. I just mean that you said to remove the bindings. Some people might think that you **must** remove those bindings to make ```v-html``` work.

Comment: Yeah you're right , some people could define the id and target values as data or computed property